# jQuery's visible upon scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

I try to use [jQuery visible](https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-visible) plugin to detect if an element is or isn't visible in the viewport. I use a code like this:

```
animateFrontPage: function(){
    var apps = 0;
    if($('#apps-shelf').visible(true)) {
        apps = 1;
        if(apps == 1) {
            $('#apps-shelf li').velocity("transition.bounceUpIn", { stagger: 150 });
            apps = 0
        }
    }
}
```

and I run it with scroll function:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    Functions.animateFrontPage();
});
```

The problem is - animation repeats itself with every scroll. What can I do to prevent it?

Comment: you could use a flag. set it to true once the animation has been completed once & only do the animation if the flag is false.

Comment: I believe I did. But it resets with scroll. If you mean something else, please post an example.

Comment: Do you want the animation to happen only once? So if you scroll, see the animation, scroll away, then scroll back - you only ever see it once?

Comment: I want it to happen only once, after I scroll further and then go back, it shoudn't animate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the animation to show once, what you could do is add a class to the element to flag that it is finished - then each time you only carry out the animation if the element does not have this class. Perhaps something along these lines :

```
animateFrontPage: function(){
    var $el = $('#apps-shelf');
    if($el.visible(true) && !$el.hasClass('finished')) {
        $el.addClass('finished');
        $el.find('li').velocity("transition.bounceUpIn", { stagger: 150 });
    }
}
```

**Update**

This is the else statement you need if you want the other animation to run on these conditions : **a)** the animation of the first element `$('#apps-shelf')` has already happened and **b)** the element `$('#apps-shelf')` is no longer visible on the screen (you have scrolled past it for example)

```
animateFrontPage: function(){
    var $el = $('#apps-shelf');
    if($el.visible(true) && !$el.hasClass('finished')) {
        $el.addClass('finished');
        $el.find('li').velocity("transition.bounceUpIn", { stagger: 150 });
    } else if (!$el.visible(true) && $el.hasClass('finished')){
        //other animation here
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that works, but if I wanted it to trigger other animation when it's gone? Tried adding `else removeClass` but it runs loop.

Comment: I've updated my answer above. I assume by 'when it's gone' you meant once the original element we have animated is off the screen? If not please explain in a bit more detail. But hopefully the update above should be what you're after =)